# Regex email address validation

Tags: java, regex, email

**Can someone please explain this java Regex to me?**

```
^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|in|aero|jobs|museum)$
```

This regex is used to validate an **email address**.

Comment: Is it the generel expression you don't understand or parts of it? Why do you need to understand the regexp if I may ask?

Comment: What do you mean by "explain" it? What part don't you understand?

Comment: do not use copy-pasted regex expression that you don't fully understand to match stuff...You'd better use some library to do that verification - as the Apache Commons for example - check out http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html thus you won't have to understand complicated regex...

Comment: In order to understand regular expressions, you must first understand regular expressions. And also, what @hovanessyan said.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Validating email addresses is now considered bad practice ([stop validating email addresses with regex](http://davidcelis.com/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)), especially with such expression as in your question. For example here's a [more complete expression](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

As for this expression let's break it in parts:

Beginning of the matched string

```
^
```

Matches at least one character from the list

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+
```

Non-capturing ([see backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) group which can be repeated 0..n times, that matches a `.` and then at least one character from the list.

```
(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
```

Just this character

```
@
```

Non-capturing group matching one character in this list `[a-z0-9]` and then possibly more characters from the following lists. Matched string must start and end with [a-z0-9] and inside it can have [a-z0-9-].

```
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+
```

Non-capturing group that matches 2 uppercase letters or one of the words.

```
(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|in|aero|jobs|museum)
```

End of the string.

```
$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
^                                       # Beginning of the line
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+            # One or more (+) characters from the 
                                        bracket expression, i.e., letters [a-z],
                                        numbers [0-9], !, $, %, et cetera
(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*    # Zero or more (*) of the above
                                        expression, preceded by a dot \\.
@                                       # Literal @
(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+ # A digit or a letter, followed by 
                                        optional digits, letters, or dashes, 
                                        followed by a a dot
(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net...)             # Country code ([A-Z]{2}), or a top level
                                        domain, such as com, org, net.
$                                       # End of the line
```

Using a concrete example, `john@foo.com`. The first part of the e-mail, `john`, will be matched by `^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+`. The `@` will be matched by, well, `@`. The domain `foo`, as well as the dot, is matched by `(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+`. Finally, the TLD `com` is matched by the alternation `(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|in|aero|jobs|museum)`.